When does a condition have to be disambiguated between declarations and expressions?
[stmt.pre] p6 says:

If a condition can be syntactically resolved as either an expression or a declaration, it is interpreted as the latter.

Since a condition only matches declarations with a brace-or-equal-initializer, I find it hard to come up with an example that isn't already disambiguated in favor of declarations by other rules.
Can you think of any example?
If not, could it be that this paragraph is useless?

Here are some examples:

Declaration of a new variable (with redundant parentheses) vs a functional cast followed by a call to the assignment operator.

#include <iostream>

struct Y {
    bool did_assign = false;
    Y(int) {}
    Y& operator=(int) { did_assign = true; return *this; }
    operator bool() { return did_assign; }
};

int main() {
    Y y = 0;
    if (Y(y) = 0) {
        std::cout << "declaration\n";
    }

    if ((Y(y) = 0)) {
        std::cout << "expression\n";
    }
}



Declaration of a function pointer vs functional cast, call operator and assignment operator. (This is an example without redundant parentheses (i.e., the most vexing parse)).

#include <iostream>

int r;
int* x = &r;
struct Y {
    Y(int) {}
    Y operator()() { return 0; }
    bool operator=(int) { return true; }
};

int main() {
    if (Y(*x)() = 0) {
        std::cout << "declaration\n";
    }

    if ((Y(*x)() = 0)) {
        std::cout << "expression\n";
    }
}


Both of your examples would work just as well inside an if statement as well as outside. [stmt.ambig] p1 already disambiguates an expression-statement "with a function-style explicit type conversion as its leftmost subexpression" in favor of declarations. So, while you're not wrong about these ambiguities, the question specifically requests an example that is not "already disambiguated in favor of declarations by other rules", or confirmation that no such example exists.

[stmt.ambig] doesn't apply because we don't have an expression-statement. It seems like an editorial choice not to change [stmt.ambig] to also include the "expression / declarator brace-or-equal-initializer" form of a condition and instead write an extra rule. Theoretically the rule for condition as written is broader (any ambiguous declaration, not just a possible functional cast), I'll extend this answer to either show an example or explain why this doesn't exclude anything else after I go through all the forms of declarator
